# How do I use jQuery in Ruby on Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am a newbie in Ruby on Rails and need to know what things we have to be careful about if we are willing to use jQuery in a Ruby on Rails application.

In my view page I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<script>
    alert("hussain")
    alert($('#hussi').val())
</script>
```

It gives the first alert as expected, but for the second alert it says '$' is not defined.

I have the jquery-rails gem installed.

The browser points out that I have a missing reference in my `application.js` file.

```
  require jquery;
  require jquery_ujs;
```

I saw some file examples where they mention it like:

```
= require jquery;
= require jquery_ujs;
```

But adding'=' raises an IDE error in my IDE.

Comment: if you have jquery-rails gem on your Gemfile, you don't need include external jquery, you should add `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` on your `application.js`

Comment: adding //=require jquery and //= require jquery_uj , says 
couldn't find file 'jquery;'
  (in ../app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13)

Comment: have you run `bundle install` and restart your server? adding them before `//= require_tree .` ? what output of bundle install?

Comment: @downvoter : care to share the reason ??

Answer (score 1):

Add this to you application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

and add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Also make sure you have this in you application layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Just a note: avoid using  tags in your code, move your javascript to your assets folder.

Comment: above mentioned things are done , now when i try to access alert($('#testFieldId').value); , it says '$' not defined

Comment: Check you page source, in browser, and see what are you missing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code: `text/javas` **c** `ript`. This causes the script to not be parsed.

Comment: thats just a type i have here man , not in my application , sorry about that